# Obtaining multiple varidiac class template parameter packs via factory class with nested class

Tags: c++, templates, callback, function-pointers, abstract-factory

**TL;DR** Skip the "Background" section, goto "Problem".

**Background**: I am trying to implement a template class that encapsulates a function that is a member of another class, an instance of that class, and any semi-constant arguments to be provided when the function is later called as a callback. To achieve this, I have the following implementation and explanatory `container` and `main` implementation:

```cpp
template<class RET> class Callback_t {
public:
    virtual ~Callback_t() = default;
    virtual RET call() = 0;
};
template<class T, class RET, class... Args> class CallbackCreattimeArgs : public Callback_t<RET> {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<T> owner;
    RET(T::*x)(Args...);
    RET call() {
        return (*owner.*(x))(std::get<Args&&>(args)...);
    };
    std::tuple<Args&&...> args;
    CallbackCreattimeArgs(std::shared_ptr<T> t, RET(T::*x)(Args...), Args&&... args) : owner(t), x(x),
        args(std::tuple<Args&&...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {}
    CallbackCreattimeArgs(T* t, RET(T::*x)(Args...), Args&&... args) :
        CallbackCreattimeArgs(std::shared_ptr<T>(t), x, std::forward<Args...>(args)...) {}
};
class container {
public:
    static void printFrom(container* c) { c->print(); };
    container(int data) : data(data) {};
    ~container() {};
    void print() { printf("%d\n", data); };
    void printTo(FILE* f) { fprintf(f, "%d\n", data); };
private:
    int data;
};
int main() {
    container c1(1), c2(20);
    CallbackCreattimeArgs<container, void> f1(&c1, &container::print);
    Callback_t<void>* fp1 = &f1;
    fp1->call();//1
    CallbackCreattimeArgs<container, void, FILE*> f2(&c2, &container::printTo, stdout);
    Callback_t<void>* fp2 = &f2;
    fp2->call();//20
}
```

This works, but does not allow the caller of the callback to supply any arguments. I was able to similarly achieve an arbitrary argument list to be supplied by the caller, but at the cost of losing the initial creator. I will post this if requested, but I think it'd add more bulk then clarity.

**Problem: Edited, completely rewritten from here on:**
I need to support windows and linux. I got it working with Visual studio 2017, but linux g++ still does not compile. This is my current g++ version:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <stdio.h>

template<class RET, class... RArgs> class Callback_t {
public:
  virtual RET call(RArgs... rargs) = 0;
  virtual ~Callback_t() = default;
};

template<class RET, class... RArgs> class CallbackFactory {
private:
  template<class T, class... CArgs> class Callback : public Callback_t<RET, RArgs...> {
  private:
    T* owner;//TODO weak pointer?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    RET(T::*x)(CArgs..., RArgs...);
    std::tuple<CArgs...> cargs;
    RET call(RArgs... rargs) {
      return (*owner.*(x))(std::get<CArgs>(cargs)..., rargs...);
    };
  public:
    Callback(T* t, RET(T::*x)(CArgs..., RArgs...), CArgs... pda);
    ~Callback() {};
  };
public:
  template<class U> Callback_t<RET, RArgs...>* make(U* owner, RET(U::*func)(RArgs...));
  template<class U, class... CArgs> Callback_t<RET, RArgs...>* make(U* owner, RET(U::*func)(CArgs..., RArgs...), CArgs&... cargs);
};
template<class RET2, class... RArgs2> template<class T2, class... CArgs2> CallbackFactory<RET2, RArgs2...>::Callback<T2, CArgs2...>::Callback(T2* t, RET2(T2::*x)(CArgs2..., RArgs2...), CArgs2... pda) : x(x), owner(t), cargs(std::forward<CArgs2>(pda)...) {}
template<class RET, class... RArgs> template<class U> Callback_t<RET, RArgs...>* CallbackFactory<RET, RArgs...>::make(U* owner, RET(U::*func)(RArgs...)) {
  return new CallbackFactory<RET, RArgs...>::Callback<U>(owner, func);
}
template<class RET, class... RArgs> template<class U, class... CArgs> Callback_t<RET, RArgs...>* CallbackFactory<RET, RArgs...>::make(U* owner, RET(U::*func)(CArgs..., RArgs...), CArgs&... cargs) {
  return new CallbackFactory<RET, RArgs...>::Callback<U, CArgs...>(owner, func, std::forward<CArgs...>(cargs)...);
}

class container {
public:
  static void printFrom(container* c) { c->print(); };
  container(int data) : data(data) {};
  ~container() {};
  void print() { printf("%d\n", data); };
  void printTo(FILE* f) { fprintf(f, "%d\n", data); };
  void printWith(int arg) { printf("%d:%d\n", data, arg); };
  void printToWith(FILE* f, int arg) { fprintf(f, "%d:%d\n", data, arg); };
private:
  int data;
};

int main() {
  fprintf(stdout, "stdout test\n");
  container c1(1), c2(20);
  CallbackFactory<void, int> cbfi;
  CallbackFactory<void> cbf;
  Callback_t<void>* fp1 = cbf.make(&c1, &container::print);
  fp1->call();//1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  Callback_t<void>* fp2 = cbf.make(&c2, &container::printTo, stdout);
  fp2->call();//20                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  Callback_t<void, int>* fp3 = cbfi.make(&c2, &container::printWith);
  fp3->call(15);//20:15                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  Callback_t<void, int>* fp4 = cbfi.make<container, FILE*>(&c2, &container::printToWith, stdout);
  fp4->call(200);//20:200                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
}
```

And compiler output:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -o test.o -c -Wall -Wno-reorder -Wno-unused -std=c++14 -g                                                                                                                                                          
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
test.cpp:60:96: error: no matching function for call to ‘CallbackFactory<void, int>::make(container*, void (container::*)(FILE*, int), _IO_FILE*&)’                                                                                                                    
   Callback_t<void, int>* fp4 = cbfi.make<container, FILE*>(&c2, &container::printToWith, stdout);                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                ^                                                                                                                                                                      
test.cpp:25:48: note: candidate: template<class U> Callback_t<RET, RArgs ...>* CallbackFactory<RET, RArgs>::make(U*, RET (U::*)(RArgs ...)) [with U = U; RET = void; RArgs = {int}]                                                                                    
   template<class U> Callback_t<RET, RArgs...>* make(U* owner, RET(U::*func)(RArgs...));                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
test.cpp:25:48: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:                                                                                                                                                                                               
test.cpp:60:96: error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)                                                                                                                                                                                             
   Callback_t<void, int>* fp4 = cbfi.make<container, FILE*>(&c2, &container::printToWith, stdout);                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                ^                                                                                                                                                                      
test.cpp:26:64: note: candidate: template<class U, class ... CArgs> Callback_t<RET, RArgs ...>* CallbackFactory<RET, RArgs>::make(U*, RET (U::*)(CArgs ..., RArgs ...), CArgs& ...) [with U = U; CArgs = {CArgs ...}; RET = void; RArgs = {int}]                       
   template<class U, class... CArgs> Callback_t<RET, RArgs...>* make(U* owner, RET(U::*func)(CArgs..., RArgs...), CArgs&... cargs);                                                                                                                                    
                                                                ^                                                                                                                                                                                                      
test.cpp:26:64: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:                                                                                                                                                                                               
test.cpp:60:96: note:   mismatched types ‘int’ and ‘FILE* {aka _IO_FILE*}’                                                                                                                                                                                             
   Callback_t<void, int>* fp4 = cbfi.make<container, FILE*>(&c2, &container::printToWith, stdout);
```

Comment: Compiling with [gdb](https://onlinegdb.com/SyhbX7N_H) gives the error `error: declaration of template parameter ‘T’ shadows template parameter`. I think it doesn't like reusing the name `T` as a template parameter.

Comment: @Chipster Good thought. Changed `T` to `U` in the factory method. I get the same error.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Also, you changed it in the wrong place. You need to change it inside `Callback`. Also, it doesn't like `CArgs` either, so you might want to change that too, while you're at it.

Comment: visual studio 2017 targeting win 10. Unfortunately, I have to support windows, so I'm starting there since msbuild tends to be more picky.

Comment: @Chipster I see. I changed the template on the Callback constructor to T2 and CArgs2. I still get the same error, but now also get that same error on gcc on cygwin. So I guess gcc is the more picky compiler in this case. Edit: more or less the same error. The exact text is now:  error: no matching function

Comment: Okay. I can't seem to reproduce your error exactly. It might be because I'm missing a `container` in your second example. The `container` from the first one doesn't have the function you name in the second `main()`.

Comment: @Chipster Right, I moved the definitions of the template class member functions outside the class definitions to cure the ambiguity of template types. This seems to have solved most of the issues. I have no explanation. See edit.

Comment: What does `cbfi.make<container,void>(&c2, &container::printWith);` do?

Comment: @Chipster That's the factory function. It creates an instance of the inner class (which is public atm, but could/should be private) and returns a pointer to the new instance casted to the interface type. The function declaration is at the end of the CallbackFactory class, and the definition is two lines after the class.
It is commented out atm because it is causing a compiler error: `'CallbackFactory<void,int>::make': no matching overloaded function found`

Comment: I misread your post. You mean try <container, void> instead of <container>. Same error.

Comment: @Chipster Got it! See update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200445/discussion-between-memtha-and-chipster).

Comment: Finally got g++ to compile it. Now applying some of those edits to ms version to produce cross-platform version.

Answer (score 0):

So g++ was getting confused on the template type deduction, even with explicit templates. Also, visualstudio/msbuild/windows wants the typename keyword in a weird spot, which murders posix/gcc, so I'm using a `#ifdef _WIN32`. Complete, working code with more test cases posted here for future reference. I'm gonna go ahead and call this a GPL beta release.

```cpp
#ifdef _WIN32
#define wintypename typename
#else
#define wintypename
#endif

template<class RET, class... RArgs> class Callback_t {
public:
    virtual RET call(RArgs... rargs) = 0;
    virtual ~Callback_t() = default;
};

template<class RET, class... RArgs> class CallbackFactory {
private:
    template<class T, class... CArgs> class Callback : public Callback_t<RET, RArgs...> {
    private:
        T * owner;//TODO weak pointer?
        RET(T::*x)(CArgs..., RArgs...);
        std::tuple<CArgs...> cargs;
        RET call(RArgs... rargs) {
            return (*owner.*(x))(std::get<CArgs>(cargs)..., rargs...);
        };
    public:
        Callback(T* t, RET(T::*x)(CArgs..., RArgs...), CArgs... pda);
        ~Callback() {};
    };
public:
    template<class U, class... CArgs> static Callback_t<RET, RArgs...>* make(U* owner, CArgs... cargs, RET(U::*func)(CArgs..., RArgs...));
};
template<class RET2, class... RArgs2> template<class T2, class... CArgs2> CallbackFactory<RET2, RArgs2...>::Callback<T2, CArgs2...>::Callback(T2* t, RET2(T2::*x)(CArgs2..., RArgs2...), CArgs2... pda) : x(x), owner(t), cargs(std::forward<CArgs2>(pda)...) {}
template<class RET, class... RArgs> template<class U, class... CArgs> Callback_t<RET, RArgs...>* CallbackFactory<RET, RArgs...>::make(U* owner, CArgs... cargs, RET(U::*func)(CArgs..., RArgs...)) {
    return new wintypename CallbackFactory<RET, RArgs...>::Callback<U, CArgs...>(owner, func, std::forward<CArgs>(cargs)...);
}

class container {
public:
    static void printFrom(container* c) { c->print(); };
    container(int data) : data(data) {};
    ~container() {};
    void print() { printf("%d\n", data); };
    void printTo(FILE* f) { fprintf(f, "%d\n", data); };
    void printWith(int arg) { printf("%d:%d\n", data, arg); };
    void printToWith(FILE* f, int arg) { fprintf(f, "%d:%d\n", data, arg); };
    int print3AndSum(FILE* f, int a, int b) { fprintf(f, "%d:%d:%d\n", data, a, b); return a + b + data; };
private:
    int data;
};

int main() {
    fprintf(stdout, "stdout test\n");
    container c1(1), c2(20);
    Callback_t<void>* fp1 = CallbackFactory<void>::make(&c1, &container::print);
    fp1->call();//1
    Callback_t<void>* fp2 = CallbackFactory<void>::make<container, FILE*>(&c2, stdout, &container::printTo);
    fp2->call();//20
    Callback_t<void, int>* fp3 = CallbackFactory<void, int>::make(&c2, &container::printWith);
    fp3->call(15);//20:15
    Callback_t<void, int>* fp4 = CallbackFactory<void, int>::make<container, FILE*>(&c2, stdout, &container::printToWith);
    fp4->call(200);//20:200
    auto fp5 = CallbackFactory<void>::make<container, FILE*, int>(&c2, stdout, 70, &container::printToWith);
    fp5->call();//20:70
    auto fp6 = CallbackFactory<void, FILE*, int>::make(&c2, &container::printToWith);
    fp6->call(stdout, 128);//20:128
    auto fp7 = CallbackFactory<int, int>::make<container, FILE*, int>(&c2, stdout, 16, &container::print3AndSum);
    auto i = fp7->call(32);//20:16:32
    fp3->call(i);//20:68
}
```

Thanks to @Chipster for the effort and suggestion that led me to move the function definitions outside the class.

**Edit:** removed unnecessary base template